# How can I use @HostListener('window:beforeunload') to cancel routing?

Tags: angular, debugging, onbeforeunload

I try to call the confirm before my component is unloaded, but it doesn't work.

I call confirmation by click, and in the case when I receive a false, the routing still occurs.

Probably, am I missing something?

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

Component({
    templateUrl: 'some-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some-component.scss']
})

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public ifAllowed: boolean = false

    @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
    onBeforeUnload(event) {
        this.checkValue()
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.checkValue()
    }

    checkValue() {
        if(!ifAllowed) {
            let isContinue = confirm('Any unsaved data will be lost. Сontinue?')
            if (!isContinue) {
                return false  // not working
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using angular canDeactivate

Comment: Because it should work not only when navigating, but also when clicking on any other button on the page

Comment: When clicking button what is the behaviour, are not you navigating to another page?

Comment: No. Verification occurs when a component changes or when switching to another route

Comment: But beforeonload host ;istener will be triggered when clicking browser back button right?

Comment: When you click the back button of the browser, confirmation should also work

Comment: I think you have to manually redirect to same route if you return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone comes in handy, a solution is found.

For beforeunload:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
onbeforeunload(event) {
  if (!ifAllowed) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
  }
}
```

When checking for component changes:
create a guard

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanDeactivate} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ConfirmationGuard implements CanDeactivate<any> {

  constructor() {}

  canDeactivate(component: any): boolean {
    if (component.ifAllowed) {
      return confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Do not forget to register a guard in providers:

```
providers: [
  ConfirmationGuard
]
```

and in the routing module for the necessary path add canDeactivate method:

```
canDeactivate: [ConfirmationGuard]
```